# Compilation error list appears then quickly disappears in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, compiler-errors

So I'm creating a swing GUI. The window I expect to see after running the code appears and everything runs perfectly except for the fact that a bunch of errors appear suddenly on the console just before my window pops up, and then the errors disappear just as suddenly as they appeared. I have no way of identifying what these "errors" are, since they appear for like less than a second or so. I also don't know if I should be concerned, since my code works as it should.

I will add the code here in case anyone needs it for the diagnosis.

My JPanel class:(Note: the ActionListener and ItemListener methods will be filled later)

```
public class BoardPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, ItemListener{


    private JMenu m2difficultyMenu, m1boardSizeMenu;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem m1r1, m1r2, m2r1, m2r2, m2r3;
    private JCheckBox cb1;
    private JButton startButton;
    private ButtonGroup m1Group, m2Group;
    private JLabel label;
    private JPanel p1, p2, p3;

    public BoardPanel(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p1=new JPanel();
    //p1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    p2=new JPanel();
    //p2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    p3=new JPanel();
    p3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 0, 0, 0));
    p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 100));
    p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 100, 0, 0));

    //creating menus
    m2difficultyMenu=new JMenu("Stufe");
    m1boardSizeMenu=new JMenu("Groesse");

    //creating menu bar
    menuBar=new JMenuBar();

    //creating buttons, radio buttons, and check boxes
    label=new JLabel("Choose your settings then hit play. Good luck!");
    m1r1=new JRadioButtonMenuItem("3x3");
    m1r2=new JRadioButtonMenuItem("4x4");
    m2r1=new JRadioButtonMenuItem("leicht");
    m2r2=new JRadioButtonMenuItem("mittel");
    m2r3=new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Unschlagbar");
    cb1=new JCheckBox("Hinweise");
    startButton=new JButton("Spielen!");
    startButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
    startButton.setForeground(Color.white);

    //setting borders
    label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(200,125,100,0));
    //p1.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(100));
    //p2.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(100));

    //creating button groups
    m1Group=new ButtonGroup();
    m2Group=new ButtonGroup();

    //Assigning buttons to groups
    m1Group.add(m1r1);
    m1Group.add(m1r2);
    m2Group.add(m2r1);
    m2Group.add(m2r2);
    m2Group.add(m2r3);

    //Adding menus to the menu bar
    menuBar.add(m2difficultyMenu);
    menuBar.add(m1boardSizeMenu);
    menuBar.add(cb1);
    //menuBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

    //Adding buttons to difficulty menu
    m2difficultyMenu.add(m2r1);
    m2difficultyMenu.add(m2r2);
    m2difficultyMenu.add(m2r3);

    //Adding buttons to size menu
    m1boardSizeMenu.add(m1r1);
    m1boardSizeMenu.add(m1r2);

    //Adding components to panels
    add(p1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    add(p2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    add(p3, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(startButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    startButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 40));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
}


/**
 * 
 * @return Returns the menu bar for use in the JFrame class
 */
public JMenuBar getBar(){
    return menuBar;
}
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

JFrame class:

```
public class BoardFrame extends JFrame {
    private BoardPanel panel;
    public BoardFrame() {
        panel=new BoardPanel();
        setJMenuBar(panel.getBar());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(panel);
        setTitle("TicTacToe");
        setResizable(false);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    new BoardFrame();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is what I see, which is as expected:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to run the program from commandline? Then you will see exactly what is getting printed to the console.

Comment: Just did that. No message gets printed, the code just runs.

Answer (score 0):

After running the code from the command line and seeing no error messages there, I restarted Eclipse and that did the trick. So Eclipse just needed to be restarted.